# How can I create a sequence of repeating numbers based on another column in python?

Tags: python, pandas, date

I have this dataset

| Country | Date | ValueA |
| --- | --- | --- |
| USA | 2020-02-01 | 325 |
| USA | 2020-02-02 | 444 |
| USA | 2020-02-03 | 125 |
| USA | 2020-02-04 | 456 |
| USA | 2020-02-05 | 325 |
| USA | 2020-02-06 | 465 |
| USA | 2020-02-07 | 548 |
| USA | 2020-02-08 | 696 |
| FRA | 2020-02-01 | 357 |
| FRA | 2020-02-02 | 123 |
| FRA | 2020-02-03 | 125 |
| FRA | 2020-02-04 | 987 |
| FRA | 2020-02-05 | 343 |
| FRA | 2020-02-06 | 874 |
| FRA | 2020-02-07 | 658 |
| FRA | 2020-02-08 | 413 |

I want to create a sequence for each country to later group by country and every 4 days. I'm looking for something like this

| Country | Date | ValueA | every_4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| USA | 2020-02-01 | 325 | 1 |
| USA | 2020-02-02 | 444 | 1 |
| USA | 2020-02-03 | 125 | 1 |
| USA | 2020-02-04 | 456 | 1 |
| USA | 2020-02-05 | 325 | 2 |
| USA | 2020-02-06 | 465 | 2 |
| USA | 2020-02-07 | 548 | 2 |
| USA | 2020-02-08 | 696 | 2 |
| FRA | 2020-02-01 | 357 | 1 |
| FRA | 2020-02-02 | 123 | 1 |
| FRA | 2020-02-03 | 125 | 1 |
| FRA | 2020-02-04 | 987 | 1 |
| FRA | 2020-02-05 | 343 | 2 |
| FRA | 2020-02-06 | 874 | 2 |
| FRA | 2020-02-07 | 658 | 2 |
| FRA | 2020-02-08 | 413 | 2 |

In R i belive it would be something like

```
df = df %>% groupby(Country) %>% mutate(Every_4 = rep(seq(),4))
```

Could someone please help? Thanks a lot!!

Comment: what happens when there isn't a seqnece of days?

Answer (score 1):

Use `groupby_cumcount`:

```
df['every_4'] = df.groupby('Country').cumcount().floordiv(4).add(1)
print(df)

# Output:
   Country        Date  ValueA  every_4
0      USA  2020-02-01     325        1
1      USA  2020-02-02     444        1
2      USA  2020-02-03     125        1
3      USA  2020-02-04     456        1
4      USA  2020-02-05     325        2
5      USA  2020-02-06     465        2
6      USA  2020-02-07     548        2
7      USA  2020-02-08     696        2
8      FRA  2020-02-01     357        1
9      FRA  2020-02-02     123        1
10     FRA  2020-02-03     125        1
11     FRA  2020-02-04     987        1
12     FRA  2020-02-05     343        2
13     FRA  2020-02-06     874        2
14     FRA  2020-02-07     658        2
15     FRA  2020-02-08     413        2
```

Comment: In this sample, all dates are sorted and there are not missing days. I let the OP clarify this point.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
df['every_4'] = df.groupby('Country').transform(lambda x: x.groupby(x.index//4).ngroup()+1)['ValueA']
```

Output:

```
   Country        Date  ValueA  every_4
0      USA  2020-02-01     325        1
1      USA  2020-02-02     444        1
2      USA  2020-02-03     125        1
3      USA  2020-02-04     456        1
4      USA  2020-02-05     325        2
5      USA  2020-02-06     465        2
6      USA  2020-02-07     548        2
7      USA  2020-02-08     696        2
8      FRA  2020-02-01     357        1
9      FRA  2020-02-02     123        1
10     FRA  2020-02-03     125        1
11     FRA  2020-02-04     987        1
12     FRA  2020-02-05     343        2
13     FRA  2020-02-06     874        2
14     FRA  2020-02-07     658        2
15     FRA  2020-02-08     413        2
```